# Nested resources Rails no route matches id = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm dealing with nested routes and I felt something is missing, I get this error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"consultations", :id=>nil, :patient_id=>#<Patient id: 2 ...
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :patients, shallow: true do
    resources :consultations
end
```

**rake routes | grep consultation**

```
patient_consultations GET /patients/:patient_id/consultations(.:format) consultations#index
POST /patients/:patient_id/consultations(.:format) consultations#create
new_patient_consultation GET /patients/:patient_id/consultations/new(.:format) consultations#new
edit_consultation GET /consultations/:id/edit(.:format) consultations#edit
consultation GET /consultations/:id(.:format) consultations#show
PATCH  /consultations/:id(.:format)  consultations#update
PUT    /consultations/:id(.:format)  consultations#update
DELETE /consultations/:id(.:format)  consultations#destroy
```

**Models:**

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :medic, :foreign_key => :medic_id
  has_many :consultations, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :consultations
end

class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient, :foreign_key => :patient_id
end
```

**View:** *consultations/index.html.erb*

```
<% @patient.consultations.each do |consultation| %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_consultation_path(patient_id: @patient, id: @consultation) %> <---ERROR
  <%= link_to 'Show', consultation(patient_id: @patient, id: @consultation) %> <---ERROR
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', consultation, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> <---ERROR
<% end %>
```

Am I passing wrong parameters to **edit_consultation_path(patient_id: @patient, id: @consultation)** ?

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

**edit:**

**Controller:** controller/consultations_controller.rb

```
def index
  @patient.consultations = Consultation.all
end
```

Comment: can you show your controller? especially the index action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have something like `@consultation`?

You are looping through all the students consultation, and taking each instance as a `consultation`.

However, you are passing `@consultation` as the `id`, which is not the same as `consultation`. `@consultation` is basically nil.

What you should pass is `consultation`, not `@consultation`, as follow:

```
<% @patient.consultations.each do |consultation| %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_consultation_path(patient_id: @patient, id: consultation) %> <---ERROR
  <%= link_to 'Show', consultation_path(patient_id: @patient, id: consultation) %> <---ERROR
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', consultation_path(id: consultation.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> <---ERROR
<% end %>
```

or, even the consultation's `id` directly, as follow:

```
<% @patient.consultations.each do |consultation| %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_consultation_path(patient_id: @patient, id: consultation.id) %> <---ERROR
  <%= link_to 'Show', consultation_path(patient_id: @patient, id: consultation.id) %> <---ERROR
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', consultation_path(id: consultation.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> <---ERROR
<% end %>
```

Comment: I follow your advice but link_to 'Show' get this error: undefined method `consultation' for #<#<Class:0x007fa9bcb508e8>:0x007fa9b91ab9a8>, and if I comment this link_to 'show' and 'delete' works

Comment: whih one? first or second? You said if you comment edit, show and delete works fine?

Comment: work with this: <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_consultation_path(patient_id: @patient, id: consultation.id) %>, the others don't work, I get this error: undefined method `consultation' for #<#<Class:0x007fa9bcb508e8>:0x007fa9b91ab9a8>, any idea? thanks for helping

Comment: partially, the show action and the action destroy send me the error: undefined method **consultation** but I don't know why?... when I run `rake routes` , I get: consultation GET  /consultations/:id(.:format) consultations#show

Comment: oops....  I did not notice that. use `consultation_path` there, instead of `consultation`. I will edit my answers to reflect that now

Comment: ok, I got it, I have changed `consultation` for `consultation_path` and it worked, thank you very much you helped me alot